# Google Play Games for Unity : Login ( Auth ) always fail

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-games

this is my situation
- GooglePlayGamesPlugin-0.9.39a.unitypackage
- unity 5.6.0f
- not using App Signing in google play console

when I call login functions error "Starting Auth Transition. Op: SIGN_IN status: ERROR_NOT_AUTHORIZED" is occurred

all login function has the same result
- Social.localUser.Authenticate
- PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate

how to solve it?

Comment: If you managed to solve it, you should add it as an answer rather than editing your question, to potentially help others in the future.

Comment: Please answer your own question, so others can find this solution as well

Answer (score 1):

I solved it

I used saved game feature but I didn't turn on "Saved Game Feature" on the google-play-service console

if Google's log was more kindly, no one must worst their times...